# Why can UE have multiple simultaneous active PDN connection through one APN?

Tags: mobile, lte, 4g

I clearly know that LTE allows to have multiple simultaneous pdn connections with different ips for different APNs, for example one for the Internet and another one for IMS. But what about having simultaneous multiple PDN connections through the one APN for one UE?

I found the following at TS 3GPP TS 23.401 version 16.11.0 Release 16

> The EPS shall support UE-initiated connectivity establishment in order to allow multiple PDN connections to one or more PDNs

> All simultaneously active PDN connections of a UE that are associated with the same APN shall be provided by the
> same PDN-GW.

If I understand correctly, it means that one UE can have multiple simultaneous active PDN connection with different ips through the one APN. But I don't understand benefits of this usage.

So, my question: is this approach used in practice by MNO and what is advantage of using it instead of using one PDN connection to one APN?